# What would be the equivalent if else statement of this ternary expression?

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements, ternary

```
bool wm(const char *s, const char *t)
{
    return *t-'*' ? *s ? (*t=='?') | (toupper(*s)==toupper(*t)) && wm(s+1,t+1) : !*t : wm(s,t+1) || *s && wm(s+1,t);
}
```

I have search the internet for ternary/if else equivalents, but this one seems weird because it has a return in the beginning.

from cplusplus website:
    (condition) ? (if_true) : (if_false)

```
if(a > b){
    largest = a;
} else if(b > a){
    largest = b;
} else /* a == b */{
    std::cout << "Uh oh, they're the same!\n";
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Your two code blocks seem entirely unrelated to each other. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

It is *two* ternary statements actually.

```
if (*t-'*' ) {
  if (*s) {
    return (*t=='?') | (toupper(*s)==toupper(*t)) && wm(s+1,t+1);
  } else {
    return !*t;
  }
} else {
  return wm(s,t+1) || *s && wm(s+1,t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return in the beginning just returns the result of the entire statement.

In your case, you could write this as:

```
bool wm(const char *s, const char *t)
{
    if(*t-'*')
    {
        if (*s)
           return (*t=='?') | (toupper(*s)==toupper(*t)) && wm(s+1,t+1);
        else
           return !*t;
    }
    else
        return wm(s,t+1) || *s && wm(s+1,t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `return` is not part of the ternary expression. You can think of it like:

```
return (
  *t-'*' ? *s ? (*t=='?') | (toupper(*s)==toupper(*t)) && wm(s+1,t+1) : !*t : wm(s,t+1) || *s && wm(s+1,t)
);
```

To duplicate this as an `if` statement, you'll need to place a `return` statement in the separate branches:

```
if (*t-'*') {
  if (*s) {
    return (*t=='?') | (toupper(*s)==toupper(*t)) && wm(s+1,t+1);
  } else {
    return !*t;
  }
} else {
  return wm(s,t+1) || *s && wm(s+1,t);
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I see this expression had nested loops then, Thank You.